# Set enable parent paths with Powershell in IIS7.5

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5

I can't see how to enableParentPaths in IIS7.5 using Powershell. I have tried the following, but I get a message saying enableParentPaths isn't a property. What should the command be?

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty '/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name ="Default Web Site"]' 
-Name enableParentPaths -Value true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST -Location 'Default Web Site' -Filter system.webServer/asp -Name enableParentPaths -Value $true
```